# Where to put Eigen external library in Visual Studio c++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, eigen

I want to add [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Download) to my visual studio c++ project. I donloaded the zip and extracted to `C:\Downloads\Eigen` folder. And I set the project Settings -> C++ -> Additional Include Directories. But the library in my compuder dirve. If I push the project in Github, does it work on client computers that downloaded my project? Where can I put the Eigen directory? In my project? Or is there any way to include added external libraries in project automaticaly?

Comment: You can make `Eigen` a submodule of your repository, then your repo will know of its dependency.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a dependencies folder in your repo, and add Eigen as a submodule at that location:

```
git clone --branch <tag_name> https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
```

The tag version is optional, but good practise. You can also clone with shallow depth (`--depth 1`), as you likely do not need its history. You now have a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in your repository, this is a link to a specific commit, in the Eigen repository. Once you commit+push this change, others can pull this submodule by cloning recursively:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules ...
```

Or if they already have a copy of the repo, pull latest and run:

```
git submodule update --init
```

I would add a note in the `README.md` specifying that the repository contains submodules.

Alternatively, you can use a package manager like vcpkg or Conan. This has the benefit (drawback) that you avoid building the dependencies yourself, and is the standard approach taken by more modern languages.

Comment: If I add eigen folder in source folder?

Comment: That is not a good idea, you want separate your code from it's dependencies. Modern languages resolve this issue with package managers, maybe you could try one for Cpp like vcpkg or Conan.

Comment: I have never add any submodule in visual studio c++ project. Because this is my first c++ project. Should I create a new post question for this?

Comment: Not necessary, there is plenty of good documentation on both of these approaches. The package manager is probably easier.